# How to unzip an "Algol 68 source" .gz file in Shell that is "not in gzip format"?

Tags: bash, gzip, file-identification

I am migrating a website from one server to another and am having problems with the database file.

I have created the db export file on the old server using phpMyAdmin, selecting the gzip option.

I have uploaded the .gz to the new server and have tried to unzip it, using PuTTY, with this command:

```
gzip -d db.sql.gz
```

However, this error comes up:
**gzip: db.sql.gz: not in gzip format**

If I then do:

```
file db.sql.gz
```

it reports:
**db.sql.gz: Algol 68 source, UTF-8 Unicode text, with very long lines**

How can I unzip this .gz file in [bash](/questions/tagged/bash)?

**UPDATE:**

Running `less db.sql.gz` gives:

> ### -- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
> -- version 5.1.4
> -- https://www.phpmyadmin.net/
>
> -- Host: localhost
> -- Generation Time: Feb 27, 2024 at 01:25 AM
> -- Server version: 5.7.44-48-log
> -- PHP Version: 7.4.33
>
> SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO"; START TRANSACTION; SET
> time_zone = "+00:00";
>
> /*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
> /*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
> /*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
> /*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;
>
> ### --
> -- Database: `mydb`
>
> db.sql.gz

Comment: If you do `less db.sql.gz` - does it then show Alogol 68 source code?

Comment: If it isn't really a zip file, of course you can't unzip it. While it probably isn't actually Algol 68 source code, you can just read it with `less` or whatever and see what's going on. If you still don't understand what happened, share the first part of the text here.

Comment: I guess there are two possibilities. Either it was created incorrectly, or transferred incorrectly. Try unzipping the file on the original machine to see if it can be unzipped there. And try md5 checksumming the file on the original and new server to see if there was an error transferring.

Comment: I've updated my answer. So it's just a plain sql file?

Comment: It's worth ensuring that the file contents on one side match those on the other.  Computing MD5 hashes, as another comment suggests, is a good way to do that. But I'm not sure why you're trying to decompress it.  I'm not much of a MySQL admin, but I would expect that whatever you export from one MySQL instance, you would import, **as is**, into another.

Comment: The issue was that, despite me selecting gzip compression in phpMyAdmin, the file was created as plain text. Also, it was delivered with the .gz extension, giving the impression that it was zipped when it wasn't. John, I'm using Shell to import the data into the database, and was unnecessarily trying to unzip it first, leading to the error. Thanks for your help and advice - much appreciated.

Comment: You can unzip only zipped files. I suggest that you first zip your db.sql and then upload it. In this case you should be able to unzip it.  Note that the `file` command is useful here, since it can tell you what kind of file you most likely have. Example: `file db.sql.gz`.